# Запятая перед "и"?

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте,стоит ли здесь запятая?

Мамочка подует()и всё пройдет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Мамочка подует,и всё пройдет.-запятая разделяет простые предложения в сложносочинённом. Как авторский интонационный знак возможно и тире.